# I want to know the result of the counter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query as follows:

```
SELECT ig_idx,
               ig_team1,

               Count(ig_root)
                 OVER(
                   partition BY ig_root) GameCount1,
               ig_game_type,
               Row_number()
                 OVER (
                   partition BY ig_root, ig_game_type
                   ORDER BY CASE WHEN ig_game_type IN ('12', '1x2')
                 THEN 0
                 ELSE 1 END
                 , ig_game_type ASC )    AS seqnum
        FROM   info_game
```

The result is:

```
ig_idx  ig_team1    GameCount1  ig_game_type seqnum
-------------------------------------------------------
494155  Real Madrid  11         [1Q] ou      1
494152  Real Madrid  11         [1Q] ah      1
494156  Real Madrid  11         [1h] ou      1
494611  Real Madrid  11         [1h] ou      2
494153  Real Madrid  11         [1h] ah      1
494150  Real Madrid  11         12           1
494154  Real Madrid  11         ou           1
494388  Real Madrid  11         ou           2
494473  Real Madrid  11         ou           3
494151  Real Madrid  11         ah           1
495035  Real Madrid  11         ah           2
```

### I just want to display one of the results if seqnum number, 11 in cnt is the row counter.

```
WITH cte_example 
AS(
SELECT ig_idx,
               ig_team1,

               Count(ig_root)
                 OVER(
                   partition BY ig_root) GameCount1,
               ig_game_type,
               Row_number()
                 OVER (
                   partition BY ig_root, ig_game_type
                   ORDER BY CASE WHEN ig_game_type IN ('승패', '승무패')
                 THEN 0
                 ELSE 1 END
                 , ig_game_type ASC )    AS seqnum
        FROM   info_game
)
                               SELECT * FROM cte_example WHERE seqnum < 2
```

The result is:

```
ig_idx  ig_team1    GameCount1  ig_game_type seqnum
-------------------------------------------------------
494155  Real Madrid  11         [1Q] ou      1
494152  Real Madrid  11         [1Q] ah      1
494156  Real Madrid  11         [1h] ou      1
494153  Real Madrid  11         [1h] ah      1
494150  Real Madrid  11         12           1
494154  Real Madrid  11         ou           1
494151  Real Madrid  11         ah           1
```

But still the result of GameCount1 is 11.

How do I get row counter 7?

Thank you very much!

Comment: It looks like you are putting your where clause in the wrong place?  You may need to apply your filter earlier, possibly pulling the seqnum out in a sub-query, applying the filter then getting the gamecount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should count the rows out of CTE.

```
;WITH cte_example 
AS(
SELECT ig_idx,
               ig_team1,
               ig_game_type,
               ig_root,
               Row_number()
                 OVER (
                   partition BY ig_root, ig_game_type
                   ORDER BY CASE WHEN ig_game_type IN ('승패', '승무패')
                 THEN 0
                 ELSE 1 END
                 , ig_game_type ASC )    AS seqnum
        FROM   info_game
)
SELECT 
ig_idx,
ig_team1,
Count(ig_root) OVER( partition BY ig_root) GameCount1,
ig_game_type,
seqnum
FROM cte_example WHERE seqnum < 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this :

```
WITH cte_example (ig_idx,ig_team1,GameCount1,ig_game_type,seqnum)
AS(
SELECT ig_idx,
               ig_team1,

               Count(ig_root)
                 OVER(
                   partition BY ig_root) GameCount1,
               ig_game_type,
               Row_number()
                 OVER (
                   partition BY ig_root, ig_game_type
                   ORDER BY CASE WHEN ig_game_type IN ('승패', '승무패')
                 THEN 0
                 ELSE 1 END
                 , ig_game_type ASC )    AS seqnum
        FROM   info_game
)
                               SELECT * FROM cte_example WHERE seqnum < 2
```